# WPF MVVM with mvvmlight and Fluent.Validation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, fluentvalidation

I am having a little bit of a conundrum with my newest App.

It's a Master-Detail WPF MVVM App that uses MVVM Light and Fluent.Validation.

The View's DataContext is a `MainViewModel : ViewModelBase` with an `ObservableCollection<ProviderDto>` for the ListView on the left and a property `ProviderDto SelectedProvider` for the detailed Properties on the right.

There are also several `RelayCommands` to Add, Edit and Delete single `ProviderDto`'s

The ViewModel uses a `ProviderService` to perform These Actions, which is injected in it's constructor  with mvvmlight's `SimpleIoC` in a separate `ViewModelLocator`.

Everything works fine so far, I also managed to have Design-Time-Data.

I now tried to add Fluent.Validation to the Mix and implemented like it is described in [this post](http://toadcode.blogspot.ch/2013/12/mvvm-light-and-model-validation.html) (My `ProviderDto` now inherits from a `ValidationBase` instead of `ObservableObject`. The Base now inherits from `ObservableObject`. Also I registered the `ProviderDtoValidator` in the `ViewModelLocator`.)

This allows me to have my ObservableObjects have automatically validated and to call `.IsValid` on them.

So far so good, I am sure I will be able to make it work up to the View and make those error boxes get red :).

---

Now to my real question:

I want to have a Button on the View to Save the changes on the `SelectedProvider`. This should naturally be bound to this:

```
Relaycommand SaveProviderCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveProvider, CanSaveProvider)

private bool CanSaveProvider()
{
    return SelectedProvider.IsValid;
}

private void SaveProvider()
{
    if (SelectedProvider.IsValid)
        _providerController.SaveProvider(SelectedProvider);
}
```

**Where do I put the SaveProviderCommand SaveCommand?**

If I put it in the **ViewModel** then I can only call it from the SelectedProvider-Property:

```
public ProviderDto SelectedProvider
{
    get { return _selectedProvider; }
    set
    {
        Set(() => SelectedProvider, ref prV_selectedProvider, value);
        SaveProviderCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); // Here!
    }
}
```

Which obviously doesn't work when just a single property in the `SelectedProvider` gets changed.

The other possibility is to put the Command on the DTO itself and call it everytime a property gets Changed. For instance when the Email-Property is changed:

```
//A Property from Provider
public string Email
{
    get { return _email; }
    set
    {
        Set(() => Email, ref _email, value.TrimSafe());
        SaveProviderCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); // Here!
    }
}
```

The Advantage here is that the Validation works out-of-the-box up to the View-Level when I Change every property. The disadvantage is that I would have to inject the `ProviderController` in the DTO's constructor so it can be called in the private Save-Method. I don't think the DTO should know how to save itself. It only should be able to tell if it `.IsValid` and the Saving logic should belong to the ViewModel.

I hope you can see my Dilemma:

- If I put the SaveCommand in the ViewModel, then I will have to do
  I-dont-know-what to validate my SelectedProvider in the View. How would the Validation work? I looked into DataTemplating the Controls but I don't seem to be able to make it work together with Fluent.Validation..
- If I put SaveCommand in the DTO itself then the Validation works nicely but I don't think it's correct to inject so many capabilities in something that should stay dumb.

Of course this is a boiled-down example, but I think it's enough to illustrate the Problem. Hope to get some good advice on Patterns and practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a suitable solution for this Problem, maybe it's going to help somebody else.

Since both the SelectedProvider in the Viewmodel and the single Properties of it implement INotifyPropertyChanged (trhough ViewModelBase or ObservableObject) I can simply subscribe to the SelectedProvider.PropertyChanged in the ViewModel.

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    // Constructor
    if (SelectedProvider != null)
        SelectedProvider.PropertyChanged += SelectedProvider_PropertyChanged;
}

private void SelectedProvider_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveProviderCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

In the View I can implement the Controls according to [this post](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2010/07/05/wpf-adorners-part-3-ndash-adorners-and-validation.aspx)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="16" Height="16"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3 0 0 0">
                            <Ellipse Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Red"/>
                            <Ellipse Width="3" Height="8" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                Margin="0 2 0 0" Fill="White"/>
                            <Ellipse Width="2" Height="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 0 2" 
                                Fill="White"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource=
                    {x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, 
                    Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox Name="TxtEmail" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedProvider.Email, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

This Approach gives me the Separation of Concerns that I wanted and the Nice out-of-the-box Validation. The only small disadvantage: I don't find it very aesthetical to have an Event-Subscription in the VM...